# Variable Length Array in ORTools

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I am trying to convert some minizinc models to cp_model and bring myself up to speed with constraint programming again.

I used stuff like:

```
var STEP: len;
array[STEP] of var LEGS: legs;
```

a lot, is there a way to do something like this with Ortools in Python?

I can of course create a bigger array with a fixed number of elements and insert dummies, for empty slots, but if I do this I cannot simply use AllDifferent any more, but need my own version AllDifferent_ex_dummy, etc.

What is the standard way forward here?

Comment: This sounds like more of a Python-side problem than OR-Tools-side. Could you use lists instead of arrays? I think you'll have to create each OR-Tools variable individually in a loop anyway, giving each a domain and a name...

Comment: Think of or-tools python as a flatzinc interpreter. You need to expand the minizinc to flatzinc. BTW, why are you not using the flatzinc interpreter of or-tools ?